# Specifying source code for add_library in cmake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to understand [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/ign-gazebo6/examples/plugin/hello_world) package meant to be built with cmake. I am having trouble understanding how the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/plugin/hello_world/CMakeLists.txt) of the same package is finding the source code needed to create a shared library file. Specifically, in the line (Line13 of the same file):

`add_library(HelloWorld SHARED HelloWorld)`

the first `HelloWorld` is the target's name & the 2nd `HelloWorld` is supposed to be the source (code). But there is no source file called `HelloWorld` in the same directory. There are only `HelloWorld.hh` & `HelloWorld.cc` files. And there is a class called `HelloWorld` in the `hello_world` namespace in the `.cc` & `.hh` files.

So, does the build tool automatically search for files of any extension starting with the name `HelloWorld`? How does the above Line13 work? I'm using `cmake 3.22.1` & the build is passing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's a typo and it should be `HelloWorld.cc`

Comment: If you follow the directory structure from the latest commit you'll end up here instead: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim8/examples/plugin/hello_world/CMakeLists.txt and as @KamilCuk guessed: There it says `HelloWorld.cc`

Comment: Actually the package is being able to build without any errors & execute properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to CMake policy [CMP0115](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0115.html).

> The OLD behavior for this policy is to implicitly append known
> extensions to source files if they can't be found.

In CMake 3.22, if the source extension isn't mentioned and the `cmake_policy()` command is not sent, the `OLD` behavior is used and a warning is shown encouraging developers to mention the extension explicitly.